# Including jQuery minified version in bundles causes it to not load

Tags: jquery, bundle

Ok folks, this is what happens:

I have the BundleConfig class registering bundles, like usual:

```
bundles.Add(
    new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/vendor")
        .Include("~/scripts/jquery-{version}.min.js")
        .Include("~/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"));
```

That actually does not load the jQuery file, causing bootstrap to not work. BUT, when I replace "**.min.js**" for "**.js**", thus using the debug version, everything works just fine, like so:

```
bundles.Add(
    new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/vendor")
        .Include("~/scripts/jquery-{version}.js")
        .Include("~/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"));
```

For the record, I got all the files in place; spelling checks; everything is in the same *scripts* folder.

I don't know what else could be wrong; and I doubt the file from jQuery is corrupted some how, since it was downloaded directly from NuGet!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To whoever might be interested. I just found out what the problem was; and it was a silly one.

In order for minified files to work correctly, including jquery-{version}.min.js, which was causing me problems, you gotta have debug mode turned off in your web.config file, like so:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
```

Anyways, problem solved!